# Generate pdf with knp snappy bundle symfony2

Tags: symfony, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I am a begginer and I want to generate pdf from a twig view. I installed knpsnappy and then I don't really know how to do it. I created a new controller where I put what is told on github.

app/config/config.yml

```
knp_snappy:
    pdf:
        enabled:    true
        binary:     "\"C:\\Program Files\\wkhtmltopdf\\bin\\wkhtmltopdf.exe\""
        options:    []
    image:
        enabled:    true
        binary:     "\"C:\\Program Files\\wkhtmltopdf\\bin\\wkhtmltoimage.exe\""
        options:    []
```

I added correctly this line in my AppKernel:

```
    new Knp\Bundle\SnappyBundle\KnpSnappyBundle(),
```

SA\UserBundle\Controller\PdfController

```
<?php
namespace SA\UserBundle\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class PdfController extends Controller
{
    public function generateAction()
    {
        $html = $this->renderView('FOSUserBundle:Profile:show.html.twig', 
            array('form' => $form->createView(),
        ));

        return new Response(
            $this->get('knp_snappy.pdf')->getOutputFromHtml($html),
            200,
            array(
                'Content-Type'          => 'application/pdf',
                'Content-Disposition'   => 'attachment; filename="dossiercandidat.pdf"'
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Resources\config\routing.yml

```
user_folder:
    defaults: { _controller: SAUserBundle:Pdf:generate }
    path: /profile
```

and I added this line in my twig: 
src\SA\UserBundle\Resources\views\Profile\show.html.twig

```
 <form action=" {{ path('user_folder') }} "><input type="submit" value="PDF" onClick=" {{ path('user_folder') }} "></form>
```

There isn't errors but when I click on the button of course, it doesn't work. Maybe I didn't understand properly how to use the bundle. I need your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your controller and config looks ok. Try testing the PDF generation using a link instead of a form:

```
<a href="{{ path('user_folder') }}">Click</a>
```

And check app/dev.log or app/prod.log depending what environment you are using

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I already tried. It doesn't work :/

Comment: What is error in logs?? Acces the page in dev mode using app_dev.php and check app/logs/dev.log file for any errors.

Answer (score 0):

The goal is to have an other view which contain the content of your var.

A pdf is generally come with content in database. So you have to take the content of you user, and create a second view call 'content_user.html.twig' in which you include the content of your user and you do the generation of this view.

Your controller :

```
<?php
namespace SA\UserBundle\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class PdfController extends Controller
{
    public function generateAction()
    {
        $html = $this->renderView('FOSUserBundle:Profile:content_user.html.twig', 
            array('user' => $this->getUser(),
        ));

        return new Response(
            $this->get('knp_snappy.pdf')->getOutputFromHtml($html),
            200,
            array(
                'Content-Type'          => 'application/pdf',
                'Content-Disposition'   => 'attachment; filename="dossiercandidat.pdf"'
            )
        );
    }
}
```

And in content_user.html.twig, you manage your data in twig:

```
Username : {{user.username}}
Firstname:  {{user.firstname}}
```